# Change fromDate and toDate with X values - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a bunch of fromDate and toDate, e.g. fromDate: 2019-06-01; toDate: 2019-06-30; fromDate: 2019-07-01; toDate: 2019-07-31.

I need to replace fromDate and toDate with values. My questions: 1. what is the best way to store fromDate to toDate? As a dictionary? 2. Then, how to replace fromDate to toDate dynamically? What would you advise?

```
report = xero.reports.get(
    'ProfitAndLoss',
    params={
        'fromDate': '2019-06-01',
        'toDate': '2019-06-30',
    },
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish it with:

```
listoftuples = [('2019-06-01','2019-06-30'),('2019-07-01','2019-07-31')]
for fd, td in listoftuples:
    report = xero.reports.get(
    'ProfitAndLoss',
    params={
    'fromDate': fd,
    'toDate': td,
},
)
```